# Showing error while integer is also inserted

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i tried using try and except and now it just gives error all the time.

```
def appendvalues():
    try:
        global temp1
        d = entry1.get()
        temp1.append(d)
        temp1 = [int(i) for i in temp1]

        global humidity
        e = entry2.get()
        humidity.append(e)
        humidity = [int(j) for j in humidity]

        global years
        f = entry3.get()
        years.append(f)
        years = [int(a) for a in years]

        entry1.delete(0, 'end')
        entry2.delete(0, 'end')
        entry3.delete(0, 'end')
    except ValueError:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("error", "Insert numerical values")
```

i uploaded a link for the pic : https://gyazo.com/9f731b983a8cf9096b184b5dfe181282

[image]

Comment: Your input fields are empty.

Comment: thats why i want the error to pop

Comment: Then it's working as expected, what's the problem?

Comment: what im facing now is that years list now inserts an empty string

Comment: If you fill in temperature but leave humidity blank, it will append the temperature to the list before it gets an error on humidity. Is that the problem you're trying to fix?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/b7af618b2a901dfe51d91e7bd1774213

see this the entries where empty and still it gave the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do the conversion to integer *before* appending to the list.

Also, if you want all the lists to have corresponding values, you shouldn't append to any list until all the conversions succeed.

```
def appendvalues():
    try:
        d = int(entry1.get())
        e = int(entry2.get())
        f = int(entry3.get())

        global temp1, humidity, years
        temp1.append(d)
        humidity.append(e)
        years.append(f)

        entry1.delete(0, 'end')
        entry2.delete(0, 'end')
        entry3.delete(0, 'end')
    except ValueError:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("error", "Insert numerical values")
```

Comment: question if filled an entry and an entry is empty it still appends?

Comment: This wil only append if you fill in all 3 entries.

Comment: I explained that in the second line of the answer.